# Найдите самый короткий путь между элементами двумерного массива

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Найдите самый короткий путь между максимальным и минимальным
элементами двумерного массива, если разрешается двигаться вправо, влево
вверх, вниз и по диагонали. Массив может быть произвольного размера MxN
Минимальный путь - минимальное количество посещенных элементов массива.
Я написала 2 метода, которые реализуют поиск минимума и максимума в двумерном массиве.
Как можно написать метод, который реализует поиск минимального пути?

Comment: При поиске минимума и максимума запоминаете их пары индексов (колонка, строка) и потом выполняете определенное количество шагов между двумя этими точками, выбрав начальную точку и пару направлений "вверх/вниз" и "направо/налево".  Так как можно ходить по диагонали, оптимальное число шагов будет равно максимуму от модулей разностей: `steps = max(abs(maxRow - minRow), abs(maxCol, minCol))`

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось

Answer (score 2):

Двигаетесь по диагонали min(dx,dy) шагов, потом по прямой max(dx,dy)-min(dx,dy), dx, dy - расстояния по горизонтали и вертикали, с учётом знаков, конечно